# Vulkan on X11: vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR error

Tags: c++, x11, vulkan

I am trying to get Vulkan running under X11.

I have (apparently) successfully created an instance, device and surface, and several calls relating to the surface also succeed, and even return reasonable values (for example `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR` returns two formats). However, when I call `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`, I get the following:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  14 (X_GetGeometry)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x5800009
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

The X11 Window is `0x5800009`, as referenced in the error. I am using  Vulkan SDK 1.0.5, and Nvidia 364.12 drivers (if that is relevant).

Comment: Please edit in a [mcve].

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Er... Vulkan and "minimal" don't exactly go well together.

Comment: Yes, the code required to create this situation would be 10 pages long. Unfortunately, the SDK also doesn't ship with any X11 samples (only XCB). I'm more curious if this is a known problem, or there is some common pitfall under which this error occurs.

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay, yes. But with just a cryptic error message, the only thing we can really do is guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the hunch that Vulkan was querying something about the `Window` that had not yet been created, I put a `XSync(<display>, false)` call before this one, and that seems to have solved the issue.

I am not sure whether this is required for proper operation (I am not an X11 expert), or whether this is an issue with Vulkan itself. If somebody has a better explanation, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Linux with XCB and I resolved it (with the help of MuertoExcobito's answer) by calling **xcb_flush** after the window creation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across that same error when I bound `::XDisplay` to `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR.dpy` before a window handle was actually created. So long as I keep that structure updated during resize events (with both `.dpy` and `.window`), everything continues to work fine.